# Excel formula - Calculate Days, Hours, Minutes and seconds between 2 timestamps

Tags: excel, vba, date, datediff

I have a vba script which leaves a timestamp in cell A8 when run by the user like so:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A8").Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/YYYY hh:mm:ss")
```

This displays the following in cell A8 (which is formatted as a date:

```
10/12/2016  9:15:10 AM
```

Next I want to be able to determine how many days, hours, minutes and seconds it has been since the last time the user ran the macro/vba code.

I am also capturing the current date/time by using =NOW() in cell B8.

Cell B8 is also formatted as a date and displays like so:

```
12/18/16 12:45
```

My formula  should compare the timestamp in A8 with the current time and date, in cell B8.

```
=INT(A8-B8)&" days "&TEXT(A8-B8,"h"" hrs ""m"" mins """)
```

I have noted that the date formatting is not consistent here, and I don't know if this would matter?

For some reason I am not getting the desired result and I get this error with my formula:

## Value!

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong?

In additions, if possible I do not want to display days, hours, minutes and seconds all at once like this:

```
0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
```

What I actually want is if the time stamp is less than 60 seconds, to show something like:

```
55 seconds ago

Then something like:

20 minutes ago

then:

1 hour ago

then :

2 days ago
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't subtract **B8** from **A8**.  They are Text values.

Comment: @YowE3K thanks but that's vba. I'm trying to get this into a formula so that the cell is always counting. With the vba solution that will not update the cell in the same way that a formula would automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it should be `B8-A8`, not the other way around, because B8 should be greater than A8. This change should make your initial formula work.

Second, your desired formula:

```
=IF(B8-A8>=1,INT(B8-A8)&" days ago",IF(HOUR(B8-A8)>=1,HOUR(B8-A8)&" hours ago",IF(MINUTE(B8-A8)>=1,MINUTE(B8-A8)&" minutes ago",IF(SECOND(B8-A8)>=1,SECOND(B8-A8)&" seconds ago", " just now"))))
```

p.s.: As per @YowE3K's comments, for this to work, your cells `A8` and `B8` should set to `Date` type, otherwise you should format them with the right format in the formulas. The first option should be easier.

Comment: I think the OP will need to change `ActiveSheet.Range("A8").Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/YYYY hh:mm:ss")` to `ActiveSheet.Range("A8").Value = Now()` before your answer will work, but I strongly recommend that they do it anyway.  (If they don't they will need to use `(DATEVALUE(A8)+TIMEVALUE(A8))` instead of just `A8` in your formula.)

Comment: @YowE3K good remark. I supposed that the ranges are already formatted as `Date` type. Anyway I suggest to the OP to take this into account.

Comment: Yeah - Excel is weird - if the cell is already formatted as a date, setting the value to `Format(Now(), "dd/mm/YYYY hh:mm:ss")` will convert it back to a date anyway (effectively just the same as setting it to `Now()`) - but if it isn't formatted as a date prior to executing that piece of code, Excel formats it as text and leaves the value unusable.